# Hyva Theme Magento2: Create multiselect category component in Frontend Using ALPINE JS

Tags: frontend, customer-account, category-tree, magento2.4.6, hyva

How to Create Multi Select UI Field on customer account page Frontend same as Admin in Hyva Theme Magento2 (Frontend Using ALPINE JS).

[image]